# Javascript ceiling (ceil) for -0.05 is -0

Tags: javascript

```
Math.ceil(4); //  4

Math.ceil(4.95); //   5

Math.ceil(0.05) // 1

Math.ceil(-6.75) // -7
```

But when

```
Math.ceil(-0.05) // -0
```

Here, output is `-0` but I want only `0`

Comment: are you sure it's output is `0` because for me it's `-1` @Lakhan

Comment: I also get -1, cannot reproduce.

Comment: Its ceil not floor @PranavPatel

Comment: You just changed all the functions from floor to ceil.  That completely changes the question!  -1

Comment: `Math.ceil(0.05) // 0` is wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question @Amy

Comment: Did you finally get your question right?

Comment: Yes Its right now @Amy

Answer (score 1):

Your question is totally wrong...

```
Math.floor(-0.05) // -0
```

The above is incorrect. It is `-1`. Floor is negative. You need `ceil`:

```
Math.floor(-0.05)
-1
Math.ceil(-0.05)
-0
```

And you need `abs()`:

```
Math.abs(Math.ceil(-0.05))
0
```

Comment: I don't like just wrapping everything in a `Math.abs()` because what if we're looking for the `ceil` of `-2.5`? The answer to that shouldn't be `2`.

Comment: @krillgar You've got a point mate. But see where I am wrapping it? At the last right? So... `:)`

Comment: When the output is -2 I want -2 as the answer. But -0 is not a valid number so I want 0

Comment: @PraveenKumar Agreed, and this works for the one specific case, however the answer isn't really extensible to a wider array of situations.

Comment: @krillgar There's no generic answer that can be given to this question.

Answer (score 1):

if you  only want absolute numbers.. always , then

```
console.log(Math.floor(Math.abs(-0.05)))
```

Comment: I always don't want absolute values. Only for -0 as 0 @Nirmal

Comment: @LakhanBaheti, why can't you add an explicit to check for `0` or `-0`? What's your use case where `-0` doesn't work but `0` does?

Comment: Is there a reason you won't write a one-line `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the way that a native function works, your best bet is to create your own.

```
Math.myCeil = function (x) {
    var ans = Math.ceil(x);

    // -0 === 0 is true!
    if (ans === 0) {
        ans = 0;
    }

    return ans;
};
```